# New PC pygame concerns

Tags: python, pygame

So I was watching a video about installing pygame, and it told me to download the link from pygame  the most recent one. So I downloaded that and kept pressing the 'next' in wizard setup in order to install it. However, then when I did 'import pygame' it didn't work. Then on the pygame website it gave me this command to type into cmd promt - 'py -m pip install -U pygame --user'. Then when I did that and did import pygame, it didn't come up with an error. But I'm confused because the pygame I downloaded is in downloads, so I deleted it and removed it completely of computer, but import pygame still works. Why is this so? Sorry, I'm very much a noob at downloading/installing stuff and I get concerned about small things like this, but if anyone could tell me why 'import pygame' still works, and if I even needed to download pygame in the first place, I'd very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: pip is python package management system. It will look for the package with name 'pygame' from pypi over the internet, download and install it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you downloaded `pygame`, then it just get downloaded as a setup in your computer. For now, it isn't installed in your computer. So, `import`ing it will not work, because python can't find that file installed in python root folder

But as soon as you execute this command `py -m pip install -U pygame --user`, then `pip` looks for a package  named `pygame` in your computer, and install it then the installed file of `pygame` moves somewhere in python root folder. So, Now `import`ing `pygame` will work.

And you said that you deleted the downloaded file. So, Python will not be affected anyways, because that was only a setup. Main stuff, which is the installed file get moved in python root folder. As a result it is still in your computer. So, `import`ing `pygame` would definitely work, because python can still find `pygame` in its root folder.

So, this is how all this works!

Comment: Okay, I just did that, but for some reason I managed to install pyglet by doing 'py -m pip install -U pyglet --user', even though I never downloaded pyglet. Do you know why this is? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh awesome, does it check PC first?

Comment: And does the internet provide the latest version?